# Android TalkBack intercepts screen touches: who to talk to at Google about this?

Tags: android, touch, midi, talkback, android-vibration

I am creating an Android game to help people learn to type in Braille. This is not an app for reading Braille with your fingers, but it does include some interactive "images" of Braille cells.

I have created an interface which shows Braille dots on the screen. As you move your fingers over the dots, the device vibrates, and a specific MIDI note is played, depending on which dot you are currently touching.

All well and good. Now for the problem.

Most users who want to learn Braille also want to have TalkBack active on their Android phone. However, when TalkBack is active, it intercepts all single finger sliding touch actions. This prevents me from triggering vibrations and MIDI sounds when the user touches with a single finger.

I can design my interface to use TalkBack text-to-speech but this is a poor solution: the main value of my app cannot be conveyed just by text-to-speech.

I have seen that many other developers have encountered similar difficulties, where TalkBack prevents them from creating value for the very users that TalkBalk is intended to help. Who can I contact at Google to start a discussion that will lead to a tactile-user-friendly solution?

---

EDIT

One workaround is to ask the user to touch the screen with 2 fingers. One finger will be ignored while the other can be used to explore the screen as if TalkBack were disabled. Unfortunately, it is difficult to predict which of the two fingers will be treated as the active finger.

Answer (score -1):

Another solution.  TalkBack does not intercept keyboard interactions.  You could design your app with a corresponding keyboard input service.  Make a service that allows users to type Braille with a corresponding app that helps teach them to use it.

The folks who developed the MessageEase keyboard did something like this.  Try out that app to see what I mean.